# how to exchange date from one controller to another by using services in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to get the selected data from the radio button and that particular data should be taken to that vote function and i need to view that data in another view or html by using the service.

How can i pass the values of selected attribute to another view using services?

Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <table>

    <tr id="$index" ng-repeat= "a in data ">
        <td> {{a.condidateID}} </td>
        <td> {{a.condidateName}} </td>
        <td> {{a.territory}} </td>
        <td> {{a.voteCount}} </td>
        <td> <input type="radio" name="chickenEgg" value="egg" ng-model="chekratiovalue" ng-change="chengeEvnt($index)"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
        <button style="left: 40%;top: 40%;float: left;position: relative" ng-click="voteForPerson()">Vote</button

  </body>

angular.module('Design')

.controller('MainCtrl',['profService',function($scope,profService) {
  $scope.data = [{

    condidateID:"1",
    condidateName:"test",
    territory:"APAC",
    voteCount:"1",
    chekratiovalue:"egg"
  },
  {
     condidateID:"2",
    condidateName:"test2",
    territory:"APAC",
    voteCount:"2",
    chekratiovalue:"chicken"
  }];

  $scope.chengeEvnt = function(index) {
    $scope.activeRow = index;     // get the index when changing the radio button
     var selected = $scope.data[$scope.activeRow];   // get the row of selected radio button using the `$scope.activeRow` function

}

$scope.voteForPerson = function() {

}
}]);
```

Comment: how can i pass the values of selected attribute to another view using services?

Comment: You should edit your question and elaborate on your it further more including what is you expected result as currently it's just code only.

Comment: i want to get the selected data from the radio button and that particular data should be taken to that vote function and i need to view that data in another view or html by using the service.